# linked mesh data without linking material data?

Tags: modeling

I know I can make a linked duplicate with <kbd>Alt-D</kbd>
But can I unlink the material while keeping the mesh data linked?

[image]

So that if I go into edit mode and edit one of these tiles, they all get updated, but I can still change the color of each tile individually?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You can assign the materials on the object level instead of the data level. That way you can have linked mesh data and independent materials per object.
[image: materials]